# Python3: Adding two sets of dictionaries into new format

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two dictionaries,

```
MaleDict = {'Jason':[(2014, 394),(2013, 350)...], 
            'Stephanie':[(2014, 3), (2013, 21),..]....}
FemaleDict = {'Jason':[(2014, 56),(2013, 23)...], 
              'Stephanie':[(2014, 335), (2013, 217),..]....}
```

I am attempting to add them so that

```
CompleteDict = {'Jason':[(2014, 394, 56),(2013, 350, 23)...], 
                'Stephanie':[(2014, 3, 335), (2013, 21, 217),..]....}
```

I have created a list comprehension that completes the task when the each dictionary has that year present. However, I need the output to present even if the year is not present in one of the MaleDict or FemaleDict. For example, if one year was not in the MaleDict the code would read ...'Stephanie':[....., (1999, 0, 389), ....]...

my list comprehensions are

```
for name_key in name_keys:
    for year_key in year_keys:
        [BaseDict[name_key].append((year_key, a[1], b[1])) for a in MaleDict[name_key] for b in FemaleDict[name_key] if (year_key == a[0] == b[0])]

    #This is where I am stuck. My list comprehensions dont work when there is no value for a specific year
        [BaseDict[name_key].append((year_key, a[1], 0)) for a in MaleDict[name_key] for b in FemaleDict[name_key] if (year_key == a[0] != b[0])]
        [BaseDict[name_key].append((year_key, 0, b[1])) for a in MaleDict[name_key] for b in FemaleDict[name_key] if (year_key != a[0] == b[0])]
print(BaseDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data format is not set in stone, i would consider using a `defaultdict` from `collections`:
Instead of `[(2014, 394),(2013, 350)...]`
use `collections.defaultdict(int, {2014: 394, 2013: 350})` etc.
Then you can use

```
for name_key in name_keys:
    for year_key in year_keys:
        CompleteDict[name_key].update([FemaleDict[year_key], MaleDict[year_key]])
```

`CompleteDict['Stephanie'][1999]` will then be `[0, 389]`